# How can i git pull with overwriting changes

Tags: git, version-control

I am having trouble in overiting changes from remote repo with git

1. I am on master and `git status` show 1 modified file
2. Now i want to use git pull so that all current modification are overwriiten by  pull from master

i tried this

`git pull -Xtheirs`

then in the last i get error that there is some modifcation to xxxx file. commit them or stash them. then it exit with `abort`

i had to stash that change and then again `git pull` to make it work.

how can i do that without stashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you're running into is that `git merge` (which is called by `git pull`) only works with *commits*, not with *uncommitted changes*. To preserve your uncommitted change, either commit it or stash it first. You essentially have three choices:

1. Commit your change.

   ```
   git add modified-file.txt; git commit
   ```
2. Stash your change (presumably with the intent of unstashing it later).

   ```
   git stash save "my uncommitted change"
   ```
3. Throw away your changes to that file:

   ```
   git checkout the-modified-file.txt
   ```

Comment: If you want to throw away all uncommitted changes, you could just do `git stash`

Comment: SparrowG - git stash does not throw away uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
git reset --hard HEAD (will throw away uncommitted changes)
git clean -f -d
git pull
```

clean is optional if you have untracked files & directories

```
git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -f -d && git pull (in one cmd)
```

Comment: Advice like this should come with a warning that the `git reset --hard` command will throw away uncommitted changes. And `git clean` will throw away files that are not tracked by git.

Comment: Thanks for that, will add the warning, but that was requirement of quetions